# How to change the Read Access to the users on custom Visualforce page in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

The question is about the custom visualforce page in Salesforce. The page is created for getting contacts, opportunity, loans all are at a single dynamic link on the account named "Manage portal Access" Which comes under "Customer Portal Access" Tab like details and related list under "Account" Tab.The page was created to Manage the customer account, contacts and opportunities relationship. The page contains Email, Role, Last Login and a Toggle button as "Enabled".When this toggle button is enabled, those users have access to this portal relationship. It has respective apex class also.

```
The task here is, the toggle button can be enabled/disabled by some users, this want to be changed here by providing Read only access and assign two permission sets for edit access on this portal enable/disable.
```

" As a user I want Read Only Access to the portal tab. I want to be able to view all information on the tan and click through any dynamic links, but not be able to toggle the portal enable or un-portal enable any contacts.   All Salesforce users should have a minimum of read only access to the Customer Portal Access Tab. The two permission below currently and should continue to provide edit access to the customer portal access section.

- Create Customer Portal User
- Document Manage Portal Admin "

- Whether there is any customization option like providing access to objects in Salesforce through (Layouts, Fields FLS, Validation Rule)?

Or

-This can be achieved only through code on Visual force page and it's respective apex class, if this is the case how can I do it, whether there is any certain command or method for providing access or through controller class?

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" object permissions (Create/Read/Update/Delete) and field level security (Read/Update) can be referenced in Visualforce. Something like this might be enough for you:

```
<apex:commandButton disabled="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Role__c.updateable}">
```

Check the [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) in Apex reference. There's also something mentioned in VF developer guide but it's bit hidden and not as detailed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype.htm

If you need more control than just whether field is editable or not - maybe look into [Custom Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5). They're your own checkboxes you add to Profile/Permission Set and you can [check them in pure VF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm) too, no apex required.

So... you decide. If most of the page is supposed to be identical, "just" about the button being enabled/disabled (or maybe even not rendered at all) - it's best to put the condition in the button. If it sounds like you need 2 different layouts - having 2 big blocks of code and one or another rendered might be cleaner to maintain and test.

P.S. Remember that good tester can activate the button using browser's developer tools. You should make similar "is field accessible / is custom permission assigned" check in Apex that runs on button click.

Comment: This the code of that Button, What can I change here to disable the button for users and what is the logic I can use here to assign the permission set for this button


"  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!conObj.isActive}">
<apex:actionSupport oncomplete="tabFunction ()" event="onchange" action="{!CallPortalEnabledMethod}" reRender="errormsg,togglemessage,outputpanel" status="spin">
<apex:param name="conId" value="{!conObj.objContact.Id}" assignTo="{!particularContactId}"/>
</apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputCheckbox>  "

Comment: Experiment with changing 1st tag to something like `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!conObj.isActive}" disabled="{!!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Role__c.updateable}">`, should render the checkbox but disabled. or `rendered="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Role__c.updateable}"` if you want to completely show/hide it. And control it by giving/ removing the user right to read the Contact.Role__c field in profile/permission sets.

Comment: How to use if condition inside the " disabled " attribute of the above code.? The mentioned Permission sets, I have used the logic as the OR condition for these permission sets on disabled logic.

<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!conObj.isActive}" disabled="{!IF(OR(PermissionSet=='Create_Customer_Portal_User' , PermissionSet=='Document_Manager_Portal_Admin'), false, true)}">

And how to call a Permission set inside a IF Condition, for Object and Field calling we use $ , is there anything specific to call Permission set and its name.

Comment: Not by perm set's name. If you really want to do it by name you'd have to query the PermissionSetAssignment table in apex, put results in variable (or make a function that checks that, returns boolean and simply `disabled="{!!isAllowedToDoX}"`. But it's bit error prone, if the perm set ever changes or new perm set gets created that needs to do X, Y and Z - problem. It's better to make a "custom permission", tick it in your permsets and then check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm

Comment: I tried this code, but its not working, can you elaborate exactly what this code does??

<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!conObj.isActive}" disabled="{!!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Role__c.updateable}">

The toggle is still editable.

Comment: But this logic is working I could disable the button for the user roles.
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!conObj.isActive}" disabled="{!!$ObjectType.User.fields.User_Role__c.updateable}">

But how can check this ,whether its working for the given permission sets and how could I include those permsets in this logic?